# VDCAssistant HIGH CPU

Tags: macos, high-sierra, processor

I have noticed that VDCAssistant was causing the computer to be extremely slow due to CPU usage in excess of 90%.

Here is the path of VDCAssistant.

> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMediaIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/VDC.plugin/Contents/Resources/VDCAssistant

When, I ran the following command:

> lsof | grep -i "VDC"

I get all sorts of stuff related to IOUSBFamily, AppleIntelHSWVA, GeForceVADriver, and some /dev/null entries.

When I terminated the process of  "/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreMediaIO.framework/Versions/A/Resources/VDC.plugin/Contents/Resources/VDCAssistant" everything seems to go back to normal.  I know that this process will relaunch and cause further slow downs.

Does anybody know what might be causing this and how I can fix it?

Comment: VDCAssistant is the process which controls the webcam. Some info [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7947713).

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I am wondering what can cause the VDC Assistant to pull so much resources and how we can resolve it.

Comment: Do you use now, or have you ever used, video conferencing software such as Skype or Face Time? Have you installed any remote meeting software of any kind which may have installed a video component even though you never used it? Crucial question: does your Mac have a built-in camera?

Comment: Yes, the Mac has a built in camera.  Yes, Skype, Microsoft Teams is installed.  It never had a problem until last week.  Now, I just want to disable that component as the camera is never used.